# Why does python exception behavior depend on argv[0]?

Tags: python, linux, exception

I'm working on a linux system where unhandled python exceptions cause scripts to hang rather than exit with a stack trace.  I realized that it seems to depend on the path of the script.  For example, this works as expected

```
$ echo 'raise Exception("This is a test exception.")' > test-exception.py
$ python test-exception.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-exception.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise Exception("This is a test exception.")
Exception: This is a test exception.
```

But this hangs indefinitely

```
$ python $PWD/test-exception.py
```

If I send the process SIGINT by pressing CTRL-C, then the stack trace prints as usual and the program returns.

I can't replicate this behavior on various other machines, so I suspect the machine is fubar and some system call is hanging. Here are the last few lines of strace output

```
$ strace python $PWD/test-exception.py
[... snip]
munmap(0x7f33193d8000, 266240)          = 0
brk(0x24a9000)                          = 0x24a9000
brk(0x24e1000)                          = 0x24e1000
close(4)                                = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/abrt/abrt.socket"}, 27
```

What's going on? Why does argv[0] change exception handling?

Comment: What's the expansion of `$PWD`? I imagine that's the answer.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like an SELinux thing. I can't repro it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the related question, which points to SELinux as the problem. However it doesn't answer why argv[0] causes python to handle exceptions differently.

Comment: It's an `abrtd/libreport` problem. Why doesn't `abrtd` catch python crashing when it's run without an absolute path? Maybe `libreport` is configured that way. How is python mentioned in `report_event.conf`? Try asking on Super User.

Comment: Oh now I understand. I thought python was doing something different in the two cases.  I was ignorant of abrtd and didn't realize it could affect program execution.

Comment: some distributions put things like this in `sitecustomize.py`, you should probably have a look there.